# TurboBridge integration with salesforce

Tags: api, callout

I am trying to integrate turboBridge with salesforce 
Check the documentation here "http://www.turbobridge.com/api/2.0/"

I am sending a json like this `{
    "request" : {
        "authAccount" : {
            "email"     : "email.com",
            "password"  : "test",
            "partnerID" : "test",
            "accountID" : "test"
        },
        "requestList" : [
            {
                "setBridgeUserID" : {
                    "conferenceID" : "test",
                    "userID" : "test"
                }
             },
              {
                "setBridgeUserID" : {
                    "conferenceID" : "test",
                    "userID" : "test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

This is returning a error `<response><error code="ERR_API_MISSING_AUTH_PARAMETER" message="Your request does not contain any authentication parameters"/></response>`

what should i set in Authorization header

Comment: Read the Introduction page at http://www.turbobridge.com/api/2.0/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the thing that I was doing wrong was not setting header `req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`
after doin this the issue was resolved :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete blog for the integration that we did.

http://dontsuckatsfdc.blogspot.in/2015/08/turbobridge-integration-with-salesforce.html

Answer (score -1):

your api should give you a key, then include that key in your header.
it normally follows a format similar to this

```
    req.setHeader('X-Query-Key', 'YOURKEYHERE');
```

then place that in your json request header in order to validate your json request